# Absolute sum of Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth and rapidly decaying function. Is it true that $\sum_n|\hat f(n)|\leq C \sum_n |f(n)|$ for some constant independent of $f$?

Thanks! Can we say that $\sum_n|\hat f(n)|\leq C \|f\|_1$ for some constant independent of $f$? How about the same question for periodic function?

Answer (score 3):

The desired inequality does not hold. For example, take $f$ to be (not identically zero) non-negative smooth with support between $1/4$ and $3/4$, so $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. But the Fourier transform of $f$ at $0$ is the integral of $f$, which is strictly positive.

True, Poisson summation holds, but does not bear upon the question at hand.

Comment: To be extra picky, you should rule out $f = 0$ ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, we know the following fact about Fourier coefficients

> Theorem. If $f$ is in $L_2([-\pi,\pi])$, then its sequence of Fourier coefficients is in $l_{2}$,

where $l_2$ is the space of square summable sequences.

Comment: How is this relevant for the question at hand?

Comment: It is indirectly relevant since it is a pointer in the direction of the true state of affairs---one should not expect boundedness on an $L^p$-space or between an $L^p$-space and $\ell^p$ for the (discrete or continuous) Fourier transform, but rather from $L^p$ to $L^q$ or $\ell^q$ where $p$ and $q$ are conjugate.  Such results can be obtained from the $L^2$ case mentioned here and the case  $p=1$, $q=\infty$ which is the easiest one using standard interpolation theory for operators between Banach spaces.  The best reference for this is probably still Zygmund's classical text.